# Get All possible matches between forward slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get all possible matches of a string with forward slashes '/' using regex.

I would like to regex that matches all the possibilities of a string between slashes but excludes a part which has no ending '/'

For example a string `/greatgrandparent/grandparent/parent/child`

it should return something like this:

`/greatgrandparent/`

`/greatgrandparent/grandparent/`

`/greatgrandparent/grandparent/parent/`

Comment: I don't think a regex will match a string in the same spot multiple times. Your best bet is to do something like `myString.split('/')` to get an array of each part between a slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex that will get each word that begins with a `/` and a positive lookahead for the `/` character is this `/\/\w+(?=\/)/g`

You can use the `match()` function that will place each word it finds in an array. You can then loop through the array to combine the different results. Check out the snippet below.

```js
var str = `/greatgrandparent/grandparent/parent/child`;
var strArr = str.match(/\/\w+(?=\/)/g);
console.log(strArr);
var strLoop = ``;
for (i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
  strLoop += strArr[i];
  document.write(`${strLoop}<br>`);
}
```